# XSLT 2.0 sorting with key position and zero values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0

im stuck with this xslt sorting problem:

I'd like to be able to sort a list of elements according to a key (weight). The key is the position in the sorted list result. The problem is that the input list has key-position values with zero and the result should keep these order when no position is assigned.

example:
input list:

```
<document>
    <HTML weight="7"><DATA>AAA</DATA></HTML>
    <NEWS weight="5"><DATA>BBB</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="2"><DATA>CCC</DATA></NEWS>
    <ASSET weight="0"><DATA>DDD</DATA></ASSET>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>EEE</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>FFF</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>GGG</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>HHH</DATA></NEWS>
    <ASSET weight="0"><DATA>III</DATA></NEWS>
    <HTML weight="0"><DATA>JJJ</DATA></NEWS>
</document>
```

goal:

```
<document>
    <ASSET weight="0"><DATA>DDD</DATA></ASSET>
    <NEWS weight="2"><DATA>CCC</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>EEE</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>FFF</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="5"><DATA>BBB</DATA></NEWS>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>GGG</DATA></NEWS>
    <HTML weight="7"><DATA>AAA</DATA></HTML>
    <NEWS weight="0"><DATA>HHH</DATA></NEWS>
    <ASSET weight="0"><DATA>III</DATA></NEWS>
    <HTML weight="0"><DATA>JJJ</DATA></NEWS>
</document>
```

DATA node content no matter in the sorting algorithm.

```
<ASSET weight="0"><DATA>DDD</DATA></ASSET> must be the first "zero" weight item because there isn't a weight=1 in the input list.
<NEWS weight="2"><DATA>CCC</DATA></NEWS> is the second element because weight=2=position in the result list.
<NEWS weight="0"><DATA>EEE</DATA></NEWS> must be the second "zero" because there isn't a weight=3 in the input list.
and so on
```

thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of input and the expected result **as code**?

Comment: And, of course, your current XSLT code as code. Since you identified a problem with your approach I assume you tested this.

Comment: This seems very similar to the problem posed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450926/sorting-in-xslt-from-two-xml-files/24464012#24464012

Comment: Yep, Michael is right, he already answer to a similar question in the link. Just map the "reserved elements" with your elements having @weight > 0 and "ordinary member" with @weight=0 and you got the answer !